# Will the application built by visual studio 2012 be Metro style by default?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I am planning to build up an application which can run on both windows 7 & 8. And also I want it to be Metro (Modern UI) style. My question, if I build an application using visual studio 2012, will it be Metro style by default.

Answer (score 1):

Nope

Metro style is for windows 8 only. If you want to create an app to run on both win8 and win7, you have to create a normal windows desktop application. Also bear in mind that such an app will not work on the cheaper (WinRT versions) of the surface tablets

Comment: If you want to build a Modern UI style app for Windows 7, you can take a look to MahApps.Metro, http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 APP can be more specifically called as the apps that can be installed and used from windows app store only. The are metrois by nature. But if you dive into the project for such kind of app you will observe the Metro style is just a theme applied as CSS or Theme.xaml in WPF and Silverlight.

You can create a libraries that can be used to target multiple platform. Also there are few Metro style themes available for .NET 4.0 and 4.5 application which are intended to run on Windows 7 to keep the UI layout consistent.

Comment: "Can be installed from Windows store only" is not correct. To install a Windows Store App directly on a Win8 machine "only" sideloading must be enabled. This could be achieved when using Win8 Enterprise and installing from a domain. Another option is to get a somehow ominous sideloading product key from Microsoft and activate this once on the machine. A trick is to just get a developer license but this is just good for one month and must be renewed then.

Comment: Yes i agree with the point, but this is something a "Developer" can do flawlessly. But if i see this case from a layman user's perspective i think saying "Can be installed from Windows store only" will make it better to understand the usability of the app. Because you making the application for some targeted users and you can decide that depending upon what are the general characteristics of those users. Also Windows 8 is a touch OS and main target of this OS would be touch enabled device owning users. Most of the starter versions of Win 8 will be "Win 8 RT" which may not have those features.

Comment: Agreed. I just had the scenario in mind that a company wants to deploy apps to their customers, skipping the Store.